# EasyMock Assertion Error for JdbcTemplate - Unexpected Method call

Tags: java, spring, junit, easymock

I'm trying to test a `jdbctemplate.queryForObject()` call using Easymock but I'm getting some `Assertion error: Unexpected method call JdbcTemplate.queryForObject :  expected: 1, actual: 0`

I tried to refer other answers on SO that  had some similar issue and tried to implement them, but that didn't help and I'm still stuck at same place. I also tried passing the values as `EasyMock.isA()` or `eq()` but still same error. Please suggest what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using EasyMock 3.5.1

**AuthenticationDaoImpl.java**

```
public boolean checkIfCallExist(String ucid){
        String decision = null;
        String sql = "select count(*) from tablename where ucid=?"
        decision = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{ucid}, String.class);
        return (Integer.parseInt(decision)>0);
    }
```

**AuthenticationDaoImplTest.java**

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationDaoImplTest {

    @TestSubject
    private AuthenticationDaoImpl authenticationDaoImpl = new AuthenticationDaoImpl();

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Test
    public void checkIfCallExistTest(){
        String sql = "select count(*) from tablename where ucid=?";
        Object[] params = new Object[] { "testucid" };
        EasyMock.expect(this.jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(sql, params, String.class)).andReturn("0");
        EasyMock.replay(this.jdbcTemplateObject);
        boolean res = this.authenticationDaoImpl.checkIfCallExist("testUcid");
        assertEquals(false, res);
    }
}
```

**Error Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call JdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from tablename where ucid=?", ["testUcid"], class java.lang.String):
    JdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from tablename where ucid=?", ["testucid"], class java.lang.String): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a2fb2844.queryForObject(<generated>)
    at org.authenticationint.dao.AuthenticationDaoImpl.checkIfCallExist(AuthenticationDaoImpl.java:53)
    at org.authenticationint.dao.AuthenticationDaoImplTest.checkIfCallExistTest(AuthenticationDaoImplTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the parameter.

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { "testucid" }

this.authenticationDaoImpl.checkIfCallExist("testUcid"); // should be testucid
```

Comment: Ughh!! How some small typo goes unnoticed for hours. Thanks for pointing out. It works now.